# Multivariate polynomial representation

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning

I'm working on a machine learning library (as a hobby project) and having implemented linear regression, I started investigating non-linear, polynomial regression. Representing an univariate polynomial in code is not a problem whatsoever, but what about the multivariate polynomials (more than one indeterminate)? I'm having hard time finding any standards for representing them in code.

Example:

```
y = 1 + 2*x1 + 3*x2 + 4*x1*x2 + 5*x1^2 + 6*x2^2
```

Is there anything like this (a common standard or even a library, which standards I could follow) and I simply can't find it?

The reason why I'm asking is not to implement my own standard if there is one already.

Comment: This may interest you http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/510834/Multivariate-polynomial

Comment: Thanks! That's definitely a good place to start, but I was thinking of a more refined standard. This code looks more like an experiment on how to represent a multivariate polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this question so I decided to write my own library for representing and calculating values of simple polynomials, which you can find here:

https://bitbucket.org/piotrjustyna/netpolynomial

I appreciate your feedback!

Comment: Not sure why this Q was closed. You wrote something nice.

Comment: @mafu Glad you think so :) Feel free to contribute!

Comment: I've seen your project too late and rolled my own by then. When I get around to clean it up and decouple it from its environment I might post it as second answer here. It will be very bare tho, as I only needed it for simple operations.